# Display a custom product price in woocommerce archive page and for upsells/related products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-fields

Is there a way to enable a backend field in the WordPress dashboard to show a custom price per product in the archive page  and for upsells/related products but leave the price in product-summary?

Example: Product A has a price of 10€ but I would like to show "from 6€/kg" instead.

The easiest way would be to use a custom field which is overriding the `woocommerce_template_loop_price` but this code doesn't work but I don't understand why.

```
add_action('woocommerce_template_loop_price', 'shopprice_change', 10, 2);
function shopprice_change ($price, $product) {
    global $post, $blog_id;
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $price = get_post_meta($post_id, 'shoppricechange', true);
    return $price;
    wp_reset_query();
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've found a solution for changing the price in archive page without changing on single product page:

```
function cw_change_product_html( $price_html, $product ) {
    $unit_price = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'shoppricechange', true );
    if (is_product()) return $price_html;
    if ( ! empty( $unit_price ) ) {
        $price_html = '<span class="amount">' . wc_price( $unit_price ) . '</span>';  
    }
    return $price_html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'cw_change_product_html', 10, 2 );
```

Problem: Actually the upsells and related products should change as well on the single product page. But with `if (is_product()) return $price_html;` its excluding them as well.  Who helps solving this will get the bounty. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But with `if (is_product()) return $price_html;` its excluding them as
>   well.

Using this in place of the `is_product()` works well for me:

```
is_single( $product->get_id() )
```

*And you shouldn't call `$product->id` directly. Instead, use `$product->get_id()`.*

Here's the full code I used:

```
function cw_change_product_html( $price_html, $product ) {
    if ( is_single( $product->get_id() ) )
        return $price_html;

    $unit_price = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'shoppricechange', true );
    if ( ! empty( $unit_price ) ) {
        $price_html = '<span class="amount">' . wc_price( $unit_price ) . '</span>';
    }

    return $price_html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'cw_change_product_html', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `woocommerce_template_loop_price` is not a action it's a function
2. Use the code below

   ```
   function cw_change_product_html( $price_html, $product ) {
           $unit_price = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'shoppricechange', true );
           $returnedSignleProdctP =false;

           $trace = debug_backtrace();
           $callstack = (array) $trace;

           foreach ($callstack as $key => $value) {

               if(isset($value['function']) && $value['function'] == 'woocommerce_output_related_products' ){

                   if ( ! empty( $unit_price ) ) {

                   $price_html = '<span class="amount">' . wc_price( $unit_price ) . '</span>';  

                   }

               }

                   if(isset($value['function']) && $value['function'] == 'woocommerce_template_single_price' ){

                       $price_html = $price_html;

                   }



                   if(isset($value['function']) && $value['function'] == 'woocommerce_template_loop_price' ){

                   if ( ! empty( $unit_price ) ) {

                   $price_html = '<span class="amount">' . wc_price( $unit_price ) . '</span>';  

                   }

               }



           }






           return $price_html;

   }
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'cw_change_product_html', 10, 2 );
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this code doesnt work. No errors in console

Comment: you are saving the post meta as shoppricechange and you want to replace with the price so this code exactly works if your product price and shoppricechange is not empty

Comment: It does not work on my end. But with your code in mind I found a way to come closer to a solution (see updated question). Thanks for that! Maybe you know how to adapt it?

Comment: As you have updated the question i am also updating the answer please check if it works it was too tricky....lets see if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this plugin can help, **Woocommerce Extra Price Fields** (Source: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-extra-price-fields/)